# Is passing components as props considered bad practice?

Tags: reactjs

As the headline states: is something like the pseudo code below considered bad?

```jsx
<Outer
    a = { ComponentA }
    b = { ComponentB }
/>

var Outer = (props) => {
    var ComponentA = props.a;
    var ComponentB = props.b;

    // do fancy stuff
    // ...

    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentA { ...fancypropsForA } />
            <ComponentB { ...fancypropsForB } />
        </div>
    );
}
```

As an example: I'm using it to display tree data in different ways by passing a component that will render the data of a single node.

**EDIT**

As requested, I will try to make my question a little more clear.
There is a component that has some logic and some markup that is the same every time you use this component. But there are two (or more) places in that markup that should be replacable.

Picture a calendar that displays a whole month. There is a component that renders an individual date, and one that renders the weekday (in the bar at the top).
You want to reuse that calendar in multiple places, but you need different markup for the date/weekday components each time.

One way to achieve this is:

```jsx
<Calendar
    data={ data }
    weekdayComponent={ MyWeekDayComponent }
    dateComponent={ MyDateComponent }
/>

<Calendar
    data={ data }
    weekdayComponent={ SomeOtherWeekDayComponent }
    dateComponent={ SomeOtherDateComponent }
/>
```

So, i found that this works. But I'm not sure if that is actually bad.

Answer (score 3):

As long as data flows only in one direction, you're generally OK. Your example is a little contrived, so it's hard to see what general problem you're trying to solve, but I think what you're actually looking for are Higher Order Components.

https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e

Comment: thank you for your suggestions; while i was unable to find this scenario in the specific page you linked, i found it in a related document on that page: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html
there is even a proptype for this

Comment: in your edit you removed the link that actually helped me.
in regards to hocs: isn't it more intuitive to have `<Tree data={data} component={ MyNode } />` instead of
`var MyTree = withTree(MyNode); <MyTree data={data}>` ?

Comment: ok, so went through the proptypes doc again and i figured that i misnterpreted the "node" proptype. but there is "React.PropTypes.element" and the docs state "A React element" so i guess im fine then?